# Multiple loads of callback event in a javascript Drupal module

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, iframe, drupal

I am working with Drupal 7. I am making an ajax request from JavaScript file to a callback function in an item in a module file. The ajax's trigger is a postMessage load in a source from an iFrame in the module's template. By debugging, I realized when iFrame is loaded the first time, the eventListener in the JavaScript file receives the event from postMessage and the ajax is executed once. But the second time in a session the iFrame is loaded, the event is only once launch but the ajax is executed twice. The third time, the event is launch once, and the ajax is executed three times. And so on.

What could make the ajax is send several times while the event that triggers it is received only once?

Comment: If you are calling the same page in iframe and your script executed without context condition , your script will be triggered twice.. logic!

Answer (score 0):

As @Fky mentioned in his comment this seems pretty obvious as both your page and your iframe will each load the same JS.

On drupal.org read about [JavaScript behaviors / JavaScript on AJAX forms](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/working-with-javascript-and-jquery#behaviors) and try at least to implement the jQuery Once plugin.

```
jQuery('.foo', context).once('foo').css('color', 'red');
```

If that isn't sufficient you need to implement some kind of switch or trigger rule. Or prevent adding the JavaScript to the iframe from some preprocess functions.